# Joomla 1.5 SEO URL does not working for multiple languages--

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I have a website which is built in joomla 1.5 in two languages English and Arabic. I have recently enabled the Joomla SEO URLs and aliased all the articles with custom alias URLs. Alias is working fine on English version - which is the default installation language - but not on Arabic.

Is there any option i can specify separate aliases for different languages? Or is there any configuration I am missing?

Please advice

Thanks in Advance

Comment: and how did you translate the content?

Comment: I have translated using Joomfish

Comment: it seems that for article aliases to be displayed translated, you are supposed to pay joomfish a subscription to download some special plugin... you can translate and display menu item aliases for free though

Comment: I dont mind the url still display in english for all languages, but i am not sure how to specify these aliases in English  at least. Please help

Answer (score 0):

When the actual content was translated, the SEO URL option was not enabled on the website. Which resulted in the component ignoring the translation of the alias field, also the 'Copy original to Alias' option was disabled.

After enabling the SEO URLS options, at the time of translation make sure that you have translated the alias as well or copy the original to the translation field. No need for paid plugin!

This applies to component, article and menu items for all languages except default one.